# Is ${callsite} reliable in case of inlining?

Tags: c#, nlog

Nlog supports a [${callsite}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer) renderer which uses stack traces in order to obtain a method name, for example.

However, in C# any method can be inlined. Therefore, does it mean that `callsite` doesn't show reliable information?

Comment: From your own link - "For applications compiled in release mode, then inlining can occur and cause "unexpected" line-numbers."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thank you for pointing it out, but is it only about line numbers? Will it be able to provide a function name properly?

Comment: @PolarBear When inlining happens in release-mode, then both line-number and function-name will be wrong.